# Пример использования клиента RIO Sockets

Tags: c#, c++, c, сокет

Прошу привести пример использования RIO сокетов со стороны клиента. Например, несколько коннектов к разным серверам. В интернете действительно много примеров, но все они - серверные и рассчитаны на прием нескольких подключений.